# Ability to scroll the map when hovering marker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

Im struggling to make possible zooming the map when hovering a `marker`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/my2p15knj8 - example with `marker`

However, it is possible but only if I use `feature` instead of a `marker`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l42n3np7xm

Unfortunately - feature is almost unstylable, cant pass children to it nor cant style them independently.

**Looking** for some solution how to make able to zoom map even if hovering `marker`. As you can see, my markers are kinda big so it will be hard for user to avoid them while scrolling :)

Thank you!

Comment: You can style a Layer independently to some extent, using a different graphic together with data driven styles. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/ https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#layout-symbol-icon-image https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions But I agree it's not as flexible as a Marker if you need many different colour markers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be a bug in react-map-gl since the [vanilla JS Marker example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/) doesn't suffer the same issue.

Comment: Thank you. Will open an issue there.